# Create big fat green arrow like in excel

Tags: symbols, arrows

For my masters thesis I'm using a specific questionnaire. The questionnaire provides an evaluation tool that provides some nice graphics in excel. I want to create the same look in Latex to keep everything consistent.

[image: Green Arrow]

I can not find a good way to include an arrow symbol that look similar to the one in the picture.

```
\textcolor{OliveGreen}{$\uparrow$}
```

Just does not cut it for me.

[image: too small arrows]

I already looked here https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf and scribbled in http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html but found nothing suitable.

Comment: That list of symbols is very short (and old), it has 22pages compared with 338 of http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf . What you are looking for in in page 81  . `\usepackage{boisik} \upblackarrow`

Comment: I take that back, `boisik` seems to be a problematic package. Just find an alternative here http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Comment: The original appears pixelated, can’t we recreate that in LaTeX somehow? ;)

Comment: Please dont make anything pixelated :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could build your own.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\newcommand{\FancyUpArrow}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.3em]
\node[single arrow,draw,rotate=90,single arrow head extend=0.2em,inner
ysep=0.2em,transform shape,line width=0.05em,top color=green,bottom color=green!50!black] (X){};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
ABC \FancyUpArrow\ DEF

{\Large ABC \FancyUpArrow\ DEF}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is a simple construction of a big fat green arrow using Mathcha. By changing the scale parameters you can construct an arrow of different sizes depending on the size of the character which is not automatic.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0pt}}
\newcommand{\bigfatgreen}{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5pt,y=0.6pt,yscale=-.5,xscale=.5]
\draw  [fill=ForestGreen!70,fill opacity=1] (100,123.22) -- (113.25,113) -- (126.5,123.22) -- (119.88,123.22) -- (119.88,138.54) -- (106.63,138.54) -- (106.63,123.22) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Item}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Mean}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Variance}} \\ \hline
1                                                           & \bigfatgreen\, 1,3                                                        & 1,0                                                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

The `pifont` package has all kinds of nice arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

foo \rotatebox{90}{\color{green!80!black}\ding{225}} bar

\end{document}
```

[image]